# Sum rows containing only the first appearance of value in separate column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
Column A | Column B
    A        1
    B        2
    C        3
    A        4
```

What I want to do is get the sum of the values in Column B, but only first the first occurrence of each value in Column A. Thus, the result I want to get is (1 + 2 + 3) = 6 (Adding the first three rows, but omitting the fourth, because a row with 'A' in Column A has already included in the sum).

I've tried looking at Frequency, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it properly to get the result I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT and MATCH:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ROW(A1:A4)=MATCH(A1:A4,A:A,0)),B1:B4)
```

[image]

Comment: Very clever use of `MATCH` :)

Comment: I was envisioning some sort of COUNT/COUNTIF initially.  Like the twist with match since it will only ever ID the first matching row.  Completely different approach for last duplicate entry I imagine.  Well done as usual Scott!